# Can suffix tree be used to match subsequences?

Tags: algorithms, subsequences, string-matching

Given a set of strings, and a pattern - we want to compute the subset of those strings that have that pattern as a *subsequence* (not substring).

Everything I've read of [suffix trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) refer to computing substring, not subsequences. Are suffix trees appropriate for matching subsequences as well? Or are there better datastructures for indexing the input list?

Example:

- Set of strings: `{ab, bcx, abdc}`
- Pattern: `bc`
- Match result (subset): `{bcx, abdc}`

*Bonus question*: If the input set of strings is *really large* (but constrained by alphabetic letters) how can we *approximate* the pattern matching so that it completes in time?

Comment: One candidate appears to be what is known as [Directed acyclic subsequence graph](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82559584.pdf)

Comment: The naive solution already only takes linear time, do you expect something better?

Comment: Linear on the size of the set? That's not acceptable solution. The set can be as large as 1,00,000. But each string is only from a limited alphabet (<30 letters).

Comment: Linear on the size of the input (sum of lengths of the strings and the pattern). You might need to look at every letter, so at least for worst case, that's optimal.

Comment: Once you build a trie of input strings ... then, for every pattern match - it does not need to depend on the total number of nodes in the trie.

Comment: Building that trie takes time as well, though.